# Javascript Function Go to Definition show only "any" on VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I searched many questions but don't see the same issue as I do. Here is my problem, I can't go to definition of certain code even the functions are defined in the same page. VS Code just can't find it, and tells me it's "any", go to hell. No matter if I do cmd+click or right click with Go to Defition, it's just showing "any" on the function and not move at all. I have installed very common and popular extensions(even disabled them to try). Also I have jsconfig.json installed in place. Nothing changed it. I don't understand why. I moved from Python world and this very basic function missing is really annoying..

VS Code Version: Version: 1.45.0 ( i've upgrade to latest and even reinstalled, neither common solution solved it so far)

OS Version: Mac OS 10.15.4

[image]

```js
//I made simple code to illustrate the same problem

function b()
{
    this.a = 1;

    this.apple = () =>
    {
        console.log('test');
    };

};

b.apple() //where b.apple() cannot be found on VSCode
```

Appendix:
What I find more about it is, it can find properties inside the class, but only not functions. This is so strange to me:

Comment: add the code version, please

Comment: added, it's 1.45.0

Comment: try `function spawnScoreFX ()`, or use ES6 classes

Comment: could you please add the code not image in this file here copy-paste to see what line cause the issue

Comment: try without using this var fx=spawnScoreFx();this is searching funtion inside other funtion and returning any so just try without this

Comment: JavaScript is loosely typed language JS don't have `types`. you could add [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html) annotations to your methods, which would give you `intellisense`. Otherwise you would need `TypeScript`. TypeScript is JS with types. But you can't use TS directly on a browser without compiling it to JS.

Comment: @fadiomar, I added a simple code for illustrating the same problem

Comment: Your simple code doesn't work - it's appropriate that `b.apple()` is not found. Did you mean `x = new b; x.apple()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are tyring to declare a constructor function in javascript and to use this constructor we need to use new instant of it by using `new` keyword let see this example :

```
function Person(fn, ln) {
    this.first_name = fn;
    this.last_name = ln;

    this.displayName = function() {
        console.log(`Name: ${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`);
    }
}

let person = new Person("fadi", "omar");
person.displayName();  // Prints Name: fadi omar
let person2 = new Person("Paul", "Adams");
person2.displayName();  // Prints Name: Paul Adams
```

Comment: nice. this perfectly resolved the issue. Thank you!